# How to set up a plugin repository for QGIS?

Tags: python, qgis, plugins

I am working with  python plugins  for QGIS.I developed my plugin and created .zip file including my .ui,.py and resources files.In order to incooperate this plugin into QGIS i created .xml file plugins.xml as shown below:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
```

Example #1 testing
    0.1
    1.0
    ftp://softwarindia.com

```
<file_name>about.zip</file_name>
<author_name>aaaa</author_name>
     <download_url>ftp://softwarindia.com/abt/about.zip</download_url>
<uploaded_by>me</uploaded_by>
<create_date>2011-08-31</create_date>
<update_date>2011-09-11</update_date>
```

I uploaded my .zip file and .xml file  on ftp://softwarindia.com.
In qgis i went to 'fetch python plugins'-->repositories.Added repository as name:About and url:ftp://softwarindia.com/plugins/plugins.xml.but when i go to plugins nothing is displayed in it.

what can be the problem??

Comment: No experience with python plugins but is the url http: // ftp: //... supposed to look like that?

Comment: If your plugin is meant to other QGIS users to use I would encourage you to upload it to plugins.qgis.org then it will go into the main QGIS plugin repo and a lot more people will get it.

Comment: I agree with Nathan.

Answer (score 5):

You can check this manual how to set a repository, it is an automatic translation, but it should be understandable.

http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fgis-lab.info%2Fqa%2Fqgis-repo.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that neither softwarindia.com or softwareindia.com exist. Are you sure you're writing the correct URL? Or that your server is set up correctly?

Also why are you downloading via FTP?