# How to Update Plugin Installed Manually (Zip File)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I've created a QGIS plugin (written in Python) that users install it by its zip file. But I have problem with the updating system. Whenever I release a new version I have to create a new zip file and tell them to install the new one instead. Just wanted to know if there is an easier way to do it. For example by uploading the new versions somewhere and let the plugin get the new version and install it by itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an easy way to do these updates in all your clients. QGIS can handle this for you. But only if your plugin metadata is available somewhere. So, the solution is to:

- Upload your plugin to [QGIS plugin repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) (if you can make it available to all)
- Create your own plugin repository

#### Create your own repo

Creating and maintaining your own repo is not difficult. On your clients, you have to configure this additional plugin source just once.

To create your own plugin repository, follow this starting points, for example:

https://medium.com/geospatial-team/publishing-qgis-plugins-fb410b958f6

[How to set up a plugin repository for QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19784/how-to-set-up-a-plugin-repository-for-qgis)

[Is it possible to set up a local QGIS Plugin repository?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135859/is-it-possible-to-set-up-a-local-qgis-plugin-repository)

#### Automatically update your plugin at startup

If you enable `Check for update on startup` on Plugin Settings, you will be notified (on the lower right conner) that updates are available when you start QGIS, but QGIS will not install them automatically.

You can install them automatically with a simple `startup.py` script. Check the [startup file documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file).

Create this `startup.py` script and install it on all your clients:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.utils import active_plugins
import pyplugin_installer

def customize():
        if 'JulkAwesomePlugin' in active_plugins:
                pyplugin_installer.instance().installPlugin('JulkAwesomePlugin')

iface.initializationCompleted.connect(customize)
```

Put this `startup.py` here:

- On Linux: `.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3`
- On Windows: `AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3`
- On macOS: `Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3`

Comment: I don't want to make it available to all. It's proprietary.

Comment: No problem! Create your own repository. Only your clients will know where it is. On the server side, white list your clients IPs, for example.

Comment: will it warn the user when a new update is available that must be installed?

Comment: You can control this on QGIS side. You have the option to check the plugin version on every QGIS start, once a day, once a week, etc. Take a look at the plugin Seetings dialogue.

Comment: I've installed phpQGISrepository and it works fine except that no warning when the user uses an older version. Already enabled "Check for updates on startup: every time QGIS starts". But doesn't show updates whenever I start QGIS. I have to go to the Ugradeable tab in Plugins Settings to see them. Which is not what I want.

Comment: You are right @Julk. Plugin manager checks if updates are available, but does not do the update by itself. You can submit this as a Feature Request in QGIS issues. In the mean time, you can try a very simple startup script with two lines: `import pyplugin_installer`and `pyplugin_installer.instance().upgradeAllUpgradeable()` to run de updates from a startup script. I didn't try it, but that's what I would do.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I don't want it to upgrade them for me. But it says: "If this function is enabled, QGIS will **inform** you whenever a new plugin or plugin update is available." Which it does not in practice.

Comment: @Julk Please file this issue on [QGIS issues](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues). The feedback to the users should be improved. We need people like you to report these issues. You can ask Etienne Trimaille (@Gustry) to add this to his [QGIS Enhancement proposal](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/219) recently submitted.

Comment: Okay. Done. Reported the "bug".

Comment: Honestly the best way to have this feature would be to implement it in your plugin as you can force or suggest an update that way by checking against your repo version.

Comment: @jgrocha Is there anyway to update a specific plugin IF a new version is available? `upgradeAllUpgradeable` updates all and `installPlugin` updates even if there is no new version.

Comment: Yes, you can use `installPlugin` to update just your plugin, like: `pyplugin_installer.instance().installPlugin('JulkAwesomePlugin')`. Check your plugin key at the console with: `qgis.utils.available_plugins`.

Comment: I've updated the related [QGIS issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42752#issuecomment-818635847) with a simple way to update your plugin at startup time.

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking for a way to create a proper QGIS repository you have this script that is just perfect:

https://gitlab.com/GIS-projects/phpQGISrepository/